# How to add a variable in put files with SecureFTP job step in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a job that have some subjobs and transformations. This job get files from sftp and do some operations with those files and finally move this file to another folder in a remote ftp.

I would like to move the file into `/userName/file1/$DATE/$variable1`
where $Date is the current date in `yyyymmdd` format and $variable1 is a value that I get in a input table step in one of the transformations that I run before.

I tried to add some variable inside remote directory input text but I did not find a date variable. And about `$variable1` I do not know how to insert a variable in this input.

Is there an option to do this like that or an alternative solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "SFTP Put" step for transformations. It would be easier to inject your variables into that one if you can drop into a sub-transformation from your job.

Warning: Do not assign a variable in a transformation and use it in the same transformation. Do to the parallel nature of steps in transformations, this is not possible.

You can however modify the fields that make up for path/filename using Transform->Calculator; Scripting->Modified Java Script value; or some other methods.